# Grails with PostgreSQL not generating tables

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm

So I have some simple domain classes that I have ensured are not using any PostgreSQL (or any other vendor, for that matter) reserved words. Executing `grails schema-export` produces a ddl which when run against the same database will successfully execute, and create all tables without issue.

However, when running my grails application, I get the error `ERROR: relation "artist" does not exist`. (artist being the domain I am trying to create a sample of in BootStrap.groovy).

Looking at my database, I can see that none of the tables have been created for my domains.

I have enabled all logging for `org.hibernate`, but there is nothing there that would indicate any problem. The only issue I can see is that there is no logging that relates to the creation of any tables, only what appears to be sample queries for simple selects.

Here is my DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
    username = "my_username"
    password = "my_password"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = false
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbcreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dev"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/prod"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
           }
       }
    }
}
```

I have verified that the credentials (fakes above) are valid, the user has permissions, database is running at the specified location, etc.

Is there anything that I am missing, or any other type of logging that I can enable that will perhaps show what the error is, or aid in finding it?

What I find most curious is that the ddl generated by `schema-export` runs just fine. Does grails generate the SQL differently at runtime, or is there anything that would cause grails not to execute any of the create statements?

Grails version 2.1.1, PostgreSQL 9.2.1

BootStrap as requested:

```
import my.site.domain.artist.*

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        System.out.println("\n")
        log.info("---------------------------------------------------")
        log.info("BootStrap initializing...")
        log.info("---------------------------------------------------")
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
        log.info("Default TimeZone set to " + TimeZone.getDefault().displayName)

        Artist artist = new Artist(artistName: 'Artist Name', shortBio: "Short Bio", biography: "Bio", url: "/some_artist")

        artist.save()
        if(artist.hasErrors()) {
            log.info(artist.errors)
        } else {
            log.info("--Artist--")
            log.info("dateCreated: " + artist.dateCreated)
            log.info("lastUpdated: " + artist.lastUpdated)
            log.info("mediumImageURL: " + artist.mediumImageURL)
        }
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious problems in your configuration, it's more or less the same as I'm using. But I'm no expert. I'm using postgresql for the production and H2 for development. No problems at all. If you use H2 for the dev environment, does it work then?

Comment: Show us your bootstrap code please

Comment: Using H2 I think everything was fine, but it's tough to say because I never had anything in BootStrap and I never actually checked the tables.  Pretty sure I created a domain through a controller though and it saved without fail. I will check H2 again later when I have some more time. BootStrap added above.

Comment: Try adding "logSql = true" to your dev config and see if it is at least trying to generate statements

Comment: This seems to produce the same logging that `org.hibernate` outputs, which doesn't show any create SQL. The only output it really produces is DB configuration and simple CRUD operations (which I assume it saves for later use). Nothing that would set off any alarms unfortunately.

Comment: Okay just confirmed that the application runs fine using H2, so it is a PostgreSQL issue I am facing.

Answer (score 3):

It could be the idiosyncrasy of pgsql and gorm as it relates to autogenerated sequences for IDs as well as id being a reserved word in pgsql. Make sure, in your domain objects, you use something like user_id (with appropriate table syntax) and not id.